# Stop Windows 10 virtual desktops from switching when opening programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-desktop

Whenever I run a program that is already open in another desktop it automatically switches me to that particular desktop. and it's so annoying with some programs like notepad++ that I use for many many other reasons.

preferentially, I want windows to open a new instance, and if it's not possible I want windows to bring that program to the currently selected desktop, not switching the desktops.

Is this possible?

Comment: No;  Virtual Desktops do not work like the way you want them to on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual Desktops are not Virtual Machines, so they share instances of programs running on the machine.

It's up to the program to decide if you are allowed to open multiple instances or not.

For example, NP++ (specifically) has a Preference named "Multi-Instance", if you change that to allow multiple instances, you can open multiple instances, including on different desktops:

[image: NP++ Multi-Instance Prefernces]

Comment: It isn't just about NP++, I wish if there be a general solution.

Comment: "It's up to the program to decide if you are allowed to open multiple instances or not."  So unfortunately there is no "general" solution.

Comment: I mean the second alternative (to bring the program to the currently selected desktop) and it's up to the windows totally.

Answer (score 4):

In latest versions of Windows 10, go to task view (WIN+TAB) then right click on the window you want to be persistent on all desktops, right click on it while it's "small" and you'll get the choice to show it on all desktops or show a window from it on all desktops.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, every program has their own options. I solved this by using the ALT+TAB swith through all virtual desktops. Then when the desktop switch I just use what I needed and then I go back. It is still not a solution, for I loose time moving windows to their correct virtual desktop. But at least I am not lost everytime the desktop switches.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1240721)